# How to increase the size of the drop down based on the length of the options available?

Tags: html, dropdown

I have created an html file and populating the dropdown with list of values/options. I need to increase the length of the dropdown based on the options available. The selection should not overlap with the drop down arrow. How can achieve this? Attached the snapshots which depicts how it is coming up now. 
[image]

Comment: Reduce font size of select field or increase width of select field.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value and increase the length accordingly.

```
if(mySelect.length<25)
```

and then change the css if that's the case.

Here's an example

https://jsfiddle.net/karantewari/r5L2bcpv/